# See full HTTP traffic in Tomcat logs

Tags: tomcat, http, logging, debugging, trace

For debugging purposes, I need a way to see all HTTP traffic between our Tomcat installation and the test clients.
How can I configure Tomcat to trace all HTTP traffic (and not just the headers)?

We tried to sniff the traffic using Wireshark, but since the server and the clients are on the same Windows machine it proved problematic, due to the traffic being in localhost.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For Windows you can use: http://code.google.com/p/ospy/.
In Linux you have strace.

Comment: Although seems like a bit of an overkill, works like charm!
Thanks!